# matplotlib: share axis among multiple plots?

Tags: matplotlib

I'm making a `matplotlib` `Figure` with some number of subplots. The last one is unique, but the others are similar. I want to give the similar plots identical y-axes (`sharey`), and I can't figure out how to do this.

**Approach 1**: `plt.subplots(sharey=True)` doesn't let me make a unique subplot.

**Approach 2**: repeatedly call `Axes.sharey`

```py
        for ax in axes[1:-1]:
            axes[0].sharey(ax)
```

--> `ValueError: y-axis is already shared`

**Approach 3**: iterate through the subplots pairwise, like this:

```py
        for (ax0, ax1) in zip(axes[:-2], axes[1:-1]):
            ax0.sharey(ax1)
            print('Sharing', ax0.get_ylabel(), ax1.get_ylabel()) # for debug
```

The `print` statement works as expected. It iterates pairwise through the subplots (e.g., three iterations when `len(axes) == 5`). But only some of the axis limits are modified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to invert the way you assign `sharey`. `ax1.sharey(ax0)` can be interpreted as: *"to know the y limits of `ax1`, please refer to `ax0`"*. That's why `ax0.sharey(ax2)` doesn't work when `ax0.sharey(ax1)` is already set.

Here is an example:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=5, figsize=(15, 5))

data = np.random.randn(500).cumsum().reshape(5, -1)
for ax, vals in zip(axes, data):
    ax.plot(vals)

for ax in axes[1:-1]:
    ax.sharey(axes[0])
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: sharing some y axes]

Comment: Interesting. This works fine with a toy example (`y = [[0, 1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [0, 10, 20]]`). When I apply it in my real code, though, `axes[1:-1]` get the *original* limits of `axes[0]`, meaning some of the data are cut off.

Comment: Could you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75785697/edit) your post and add a reproducible example where is goes wrong?  Note that if you call `axes[0].set_ylim(...)` or something similar, those limits will persist. You can use `axes[0].autoscale(axis='y')` to free the fixed limits fixed by an earlier `set_ylim(...)`.

Comment: You know, I suspected that was the problem, but I did `ax.set_ylim(auto=True)` and it didn't help. This fixes the problem. Thanks!

Comment: I wanted to make a reproducible example, but I had some other bugs to fix, so I put it off. Looks like it's taken care of, though.

Comment: Happy to know both the original question and your additional problem are solved now.